# Show when webcam is in use

Tags: windows-7, webcam

On my laptop I have an integrated webcam, but what it doesn't have is a light indicator if it is working.

Is there a way a dot or something wold appear on my screen if my webcam is working?

---

**EDIT:**
I have Asus N71Ja, with Windows 7. Program I usually use is Skype, but I *might* use other programs as well.

I would need a **universal indicator**, that wouldn't be software dependent so no matter which program would use a webcam I could see it. Because if Skype for example is minimized I have no idea webcam is on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every software I have seen that comes with webcams (even built-in webcams) has some kind of virtualized indicator light.  It's probably a matter of figuring out where it is in the software that came with your webcam, though, as there aren't many universal webcam benchmarking tools.  The stats on webcams are pretty much written on the boxes....  So, if you posted more info about the kind of webcam/laptop, it would help a lot.

-Edit-

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any info in the manual about the webcam.  I also didn't see any software for the webcam on your computer's info site.

If you want something software-independent, you need to go to an electronics store and pick something up some wire, a little LED, and a soldering iron. It's going to be a pain in the take the computer apart, though. If you just want a software-based solution, there are many *softwares* out there that let you know when your cam is active. For example, "**Camera Monitor**". I think iSpy does it, also. You can also enable and disable your webcam driver in various ways. You could build a batch file to do this for you and shortcut it on the desktop.

Comment: added information

Comment: Taking it apart and hooking a led on it is the easy one, if it had a connector for it..

Comment: I don't know.  It's pretty dangerous.  A lot of people try to take apart the laptop area and end up having their monitor fall out in a way such that it is very difficult to reattach.  Someone very dexterous could just unscrew the top two screws, wedge it opened, and do the cutting and soldering or clamping, though.  I'm not even sure the wires would be unexposed, honestly.  It sure seems simple to just go download Camera Monitor or build a Batch script, though.  A program called "DEVCON"--free from MS--will make it very easy to build a batch script to enable and disable devices.... read on...

Comment: If you get Devcon, you can figure out what the device is called by typing devcon find *> list.txt at the command line.  It will create list.txt in your system32 folder.  Then, create a new file called 'disable.bat'.  Right click it and click 'edit'.  Add the line 'devcon disable webcamname'.  Make another batch file named 'enable.bat' that contains 'devcon enable webcamname'.

Comment: I don't want to disable webcam, i just want to know if it is on.

Comment: Okay.  Maybe someone else will be interested in that since these seems security-related, though.  I hope you don't mind keeping the info available, just in case someone should want to.  So, the alternative is to buy a cam with an LED, attach an LED by yourself, or use a software solution, like Camera Monitor.  Source code is available for this program, so you can see how it inspects your computer and build your own solution.

Comment: Yeah I'm considering making a peace of software myself. Possibly putting it out open source

Comment: Well CameraMonitor is written in Python.  It's not a very large program.  You could probably convert it to C and speed it up for everyone.  Maybe you guys could work together.  Who knows?  You can find it by searching for `"Camera Monitor" download` on google.  It's at SoftPedia.  Unfortunately, I've already inspected the source code.  It seems it relies on python's built-in method for discovering hardware.  It's nice because it's probably platform-independent.  It's sad cause they're using os.Popen (deprecated).  It uses 'lsof' as an arg, which python has forced to work in Windows. Cool, huh?

Comment: @BojanKogoj did you ever write that? I just got a new laptop, and discovered mine also has no indicator, which is super irritating. I'd love for this to exist.